# Choosing resistor/capacitor for wiring microphones

Tags: capacitor, resistors, microphone

I've been researching how to wire up a electret mic and found this to be very common. I can't seem to find any info on what values should be used. Most people use 1k or 2.2k resistors and 4.7uF caps.

The input power source is ~2.5v. The mic is a 3 pinned 4.4k, 1.3v, 50uA electret condenser. From my research, I assume that since DC signal has a frequency of 0, any size cap will work, but an undersized one will leak DC though, but that also depends on the resistor size. So... Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

[image]

Comment: You need to have an idea of the maximum sound pressure level you expect to support with the electret AND a datasheet for it, as well. Just to start a design. You also need to have an idea of what kind of amplifier you will then use afterwards. The value of \$R_1\$ and the capacitor itself depends on such things. (Though the capacitor impedance at audio must be low, compared to \$R_1\$, in general.) You really cannot get a direct answer without providing many more thoughtful details.

Comment: An undersized cap won't "leak DC through", it'll reduce the bass from the mic. And you need to know the input impedance of the amplifier you're connecting it to, to be certain of that.

Comment: Here is the [spec sheet](http://www.knowles.com/eng/content/download/4632/63756/version/5/file/FG-23329-P142.pdf).

It is going into an audio recorder, Zoom H1 or Olympus WS-802. I'll need to do some investigating.

Edit: Looks like the Zoom H1 has an input impedance of 2k.